# How to change the current time in the progress control?

Tags: video.js

Is it possible to manualy set the current time position on the timeline? I need this because I have several separated videos which represent one video and are playing in different players.

For example, the actual current time is marked as white dot, the desired current time that I want to show as red dot.
[image]

Can I do this somehow without creating completely new custom controlbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Middleware](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-middleware.html) could be part of the solution, which allows you to intercept and modify what's sent to / received from the playback tech (video element).

```js
var myMiddleware = function(player) {
  return {
    currentTime: function(ct) {
      // When the video el says the currentTime is 60s, report 160s
      return ct + 100;
    },
    setCurrentTime: function(time) {
      // When the user / progress bar wants to seek to 220s, actually seek to 120s
      return time - 100; 
    }
  };
};

videojs.use('*', myMiddleware);
```